Should downvoters leave a constructive comment to help users to improve their posts?
This is an old post, but it seems to me relevant today (August 2020) for the reasons I explain below.
From the site analytics, which is viewable to any user with 5000 or more reputation points, you can see that, from mid February, the number of downvotes on the main site has increased a lot. But these downvotes are very rarely accompanied with a constructive comment which can help the poster to write better questions or answers. The important thing is not to add a comment to explain the reason of the downvote, it's to give a constructive comment. "This question needs clarification: as it is stated now it's nonsense"  or "A question like this one, on ELU for example, would be closed in two minutes" are not constructive at all and should be avoided.
We should be especially careful with new users and with users who don't participate very frequently. I believe we should also pay attention to users which have received downvotes on many posts on a short period of time because this is probably an indication that they have not understood some aspect of how this site works: our help can improve the quality of these users posts.  This may eventually produce that these users are blocked from asking or from answering (see, for instance, this post and take into account that this has also happened in our site to some user who has simply disappeared), but it seems to me that it would be better if such users learn how to improve their posts thanks to our help so their participation doesn't need to be blocked (at least, we can try).
Anyway, our message should always be "we are here to help you" and never "your participation on the site is unwelcome" (and I fear lots of users of this site have perceived this message).
We are a small site, with few activity and very few participation. We have an extremely low number of experienced users (especially askers) and the unexperienced ones may need our help. So I would just like us to recall what we discussed here in order to try to be a little more constructive.


Update (June 2019): 
Lately, I have seen again lots of downvotes on questions and answers without any comment to explain why. For this reason, I have decided to reopen this debate.

 
This is the contents of the old post.
It's not the first time that this happens in this site but, since there is no Meta post inviting to discuss it (or at least I haven't seen it), I decided to write one. Lately, specially on answers, I have noticed a proliferation of downvotes without any comment to explain why. In general, I feel that this behaviour is not very constructive for the site for the reasons
explained in this Meta question: explaining why an answer in being downvoted encourage the poster to improve that answer. It can even encourage that user to write better answers in the future. I'm referring to the main site: downvotes in Meta are different.
Of course there can be some exceptions to this "rule" (in fact, it's not a rule, because every user is free to downvote without a comment, it's just an invitation from me). For instance, if one finds an answer that is spam in a very evident way, it's no worth writing a comment to say "we don't want spam in this site". In the same way, when an answer is of very evident low quality or an user has repeatedly shown an agressive or rude behaviour whenever anyone else criticise their posts in comments, I think there is no need to leave a comment to explain the reason of a downvote.
I would like to have your opinion about that and see if you think we should/could do something to discourage that practice.
[In addition to this, speaking specifically about answers and always in relative terms, I have the impression that, lately, the amount of downvotes is relatively high whith respect to the total amount of upvotes on answers. I sometimes wonder: we are really doing so bad in comparison to the past? I know this is another subject that maybe should to be asked in another question. I don't do it because I'm not sure if this is really that way or it's only a subjective impression.]

I would like to add that, according to my own experience, downvotes to answers without any explanation often leads to perplexity  the OP and other users who use the site to learn Italian, because they 
remain wondering about what is wrong in the answer. And I fear this perplexity can sometimes cause someone to not come back to ask again (I've seen some instances of this behaviour on this site, but I'm not sure at all if this was a reason for it).      

As a moderator, do you have a way to see whether these downvotes are given by “regulars”, by relatively new users or what else? Or – with respect to your last question – statistics about up- and downvotes.

@DaG: No, votes are secret even to moderators and there is not such statistics.

In general it seems to me that people upvote questions very little here. I wonder if I should do a meta post about it, since it's somehow unrelated.

@DenisNardin: This is in fact related to my last question.

Could you please add a few specific examples, so that we can judge if the reason for the downvote is clear from the context?

The anonymous downvoter strikes again...

@FedericoPoloni: I can do it, but I can't be exhaustive, so I hope no one will take this personally.

Some examples: https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/2010, https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/6754, https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/1641 (but there are others).

@Charo In the first three answers that you listed, there are rather detailed comments that are critical towards the answer (in the first one a comment even states "this is a terrible answer" + motivation). Isn't that sufficient for you?

@FedericoPoloni: Sorry, I made a mistake about the first answer, so I would have to remove it from the list of my previous comment. But comments of the other two are from a long time ago, whereas the downvote is recent (you can check it).

@Charo How can I check if a downvote is recent? Maybe you can as a moderator, but I have no idea how to do it.

@FedericoPoloni: From the profile of the user who has posted the answer, choose "Activity", then the tab "reputation" and then the tab "time". For instance, https://italian.stackexchange.com/users/677/marc-sch%c3%bctz?tab=reputation (choose the tab "time").

I've corrected my previous comment in such a way to remove the first answer from the list.

@Charo Just to be clear, I am not the one who downvoted those answers in your examples.

@DaG It is my understanding that downvotes are handled differently in Meta: they simply express disagreement with the proposal.

@FedericoPoloni: I agree. I just found paradoxical (or self-referential) that a post about downvotes without comments is downvoted without a comment.

@FedericoPoloni: A me il commento di DaG era sembrato uno scherzo simpatico giustamente per questo aspetto di auto-riferimento. I love this kind of somehow paradoxical things.

@DaG: I've now seen that, from site analytics, which is also accessible to you, statistical data can be taken. From 2017/01/01 until 2017/01/19: downvotes/upvotes = 14/289 = 0.048. From 2018/01/01 until 2018/01/19: downvotes/upvotes = 23/244 = 0.094. So it seems it's not just my subjective impression.

@DaG: Another aspect that gives the impression of the site loosing quality is the fact that, whereas the number of posts has increased a lot (from the site analytics one can see that we had 123 posts from the beginning of this year until now, but only 69 posts at the same period last year), the number of total upvotes has decreased.

@Charo As it stands, the title of your post looks more like an order than a question. Could we please change it to something more neutral such as "Should downvoters add a comment to explain their opinion?"?

@FedericoPoloni: I have just done it.

Thanks @Charo! ~

As a matter of fact, the general consensus across the StackExchange network seems to be that downvotes don't (generally) need a comment.
I'm not very keen on downvoting (even less so here, being a moderator) and my personal opinion is that many downvotes should need a comment. It's not really easy to make a hard and fast rule, but we're in a different situation: this site is still in beta, which means questions and answers make the difference in changing the status.
Therefore I endorse Charo’s invitation to be more generous in comments in particular when downvoting and to check back whether a downvote (or simply a critic comment) triggered an edit to the question or answer: this will certainly improve the quality of the site.

I found a little bit disturbing to receive downvotes without any explanation, especially during this week. As mentioned it would be a way to improve the overall quality of the site. Moreover SO launched a survey to understand why the site is perceived as not very welcoming. I think this is another aspect of the same problem

I would like to add that, according to my own experience, downvotes to answers without any explanation often gives rise to perplexity of the OP and other users who use the site to learn Italian, which remain wondering about what is wrong in the answer.

Given that I personally agree with Federico Poloni's answer, I personally find this debate quite sterile. While I think nobody has a problem with downvotes being cast, the question of whether people should leave a comment after having downvoted doesn't have a solution, and it doesn't make much sense to talk about it. This opinion stems from the fact that this is an uncontrollable phenomenon, unlike other matters which can actually be "policed" on an SE site.
Also, coming back to recent events, let's not forget that downvotes can also stem from authentically capricious behavior, without any reason pertaining to the content of the question. I know this is hard to digest and hear, but it is a possibility. There is nothing that can (ever) be done about this sort of behavior because of how the site is structured (namely the anonymity of votes). This is another reason why I personally find talking about this subject quite futile. 

In fact, the object of my post (the original title was "Please leave a comment to explain the reason of your downvote") is not to make  some kind of "police" of the site. It pretends only to be an invitation to be some more constructive in our practices. I've changed the title of the post because @FedericoPoloni asked me trying to write something more neutral, but I don't know if, as it stands now, it may cause some confusion.

I don't think that every downvote needs a comment. Sometimes I don't want to repeat things that are in the help center (or maybe already stated in other comments, or clear from the other answers), and I don't want to enter what may be a long discussion with OP.
Sometimes I use downvotes because an answer is poorly documented, because I disagree with it, or simply because I want to see less content like that on this website. It would be difficult to formulate my points in an non-subjective way, and that would almost always lead to an argument.
Not all answers are worth salvaging, if it takes lots of revisions and arguing. But it's always useful if the best answers appear on top, and downvoting is a means to do it.
If SE didn't want this, why is there a button to downvote without comment? And it's the largest one in the whole interface (tied with the upvote one).
Besides that, some people take downvotes too personally. OK, you got a drive-by downvote. So what? It's just imaginary internet points. And "I don't like your answer" doesn't mean "you're an idiot".
To answer a comment: no, I don't think that the answerer has a right to know in which way I disagree with them. If an answer states that 2+2=5, they don't have the right to get free math tutoring from me. I could do it if I have the time and feel like contributing and helping, but let's not argue that it is my obligation.

Note that I'm not making any objection about downvoting, I was only saying that, in my opinion, it would be more constructive for the site if we comment most (not all) of our downvotes.

Your reasons to not comment seem peculiar to me. Certainly the answerer has a right to know in what particular way you disagree with him/her. I have been puzzled in the past by answers (not by me) in which I couldn't fathom what motivated the downvoter. A little bit of clarity would often help.

Certainly the answerer has a right to know in what particular way you disagree with him/her --- uhm, why?

So that he can improve the answer

I have addressed this: Not all answers are worth salvaging, if it takes lots of revisions and arguing., Sometimes I use downvotes because an answer is poorly documented, because I disagree with it, or simply because I want to see less content like that on this website. It would be difficult to formulate my points in an non-subjective way, and that would almost always lead to an argument. If I have a clear, relevant comment, I will make it, but that doesn't happen every time I downvote.

In a sense, I agree with you: some answers or questions seem “obviously” not useful, with no need (nor requirement by SE's rules) to even lose one's time in adding a comment. On the other hand, I (often) force myself to remark about the reason that answer/question deserves, in my opinion, a downvote. If you reread carefully this very answer of yours, you'll see why. You write “I don't want to repeat...”, “I don't want to enter... a... discussion” and even “It would be difficult to formulate my points in an non-subjective way”. [to be continued]

All of this seems to point to some arbitrariness, almost a “just because”, which doesn't lead to a level of communication useful to everybody. The same fact that your objections are “difficult to formulate” should be food for thought (for my thought, too, of course, since as I mentioned my first reaction is often similar to yours). If you find it difficult to formulate, everybody else could find it difficult to understand.

When I have a constructive comment, I make it. But "I don't find this question/answer interesting or useful" is reason enough to downvote, in my view (and hovering on the downvote button will confirm that the SE team agrees). This is subjective. That's just my opinion. I could try to write my reasons, but people will start arguing. (And, in case you haven't noticed, we are arguing about downvotes even now, which we shouldn't.)

I think people take downvotes too seriously here. At least three people have written disagreeing comments, yet no one has downvoted me. Why? Do you think downvotes are a personal offense? They are not. They are a way to get better answers displayed more prominently. What's wrong with them?

@DaG: I agree with that and this is the reason why I wrote «Of course there can be some exceptions to this "rule".»

@FedericoPoloni At least I did not downvote because I think your answer is useful (votes on meta carry so many meanings that it is slightly confusing) as expounding a legitimate viewpoint that is nevertheless different from mine. I agree that there are answers that are essentially impossible to improve, but what seems obvious to you might not be obvious to the poster, or in fact to everyone else. [And, to establish my credentials, I have been accused to downvote too much in the past...]

I agree with what is said by @DenisNardin. In addition, maybe your last comment has something to do with what I wrote in square brackets. Namely, I sometimes feel that, if the tendency is few upvotes and a relatively big amount of downvotes (I refer to the main site, not to Meta), that can give the impqqression of poor quality.

For instance, let's immagine the situation of a new user which has used StackExchange to make questions about another language. Let's immagine that he or she is also a beginner in Italian.
He or she is used to see how good answers receive a large number of upvotes in other StackExchange sites. But I think that in our site you can sometimes see good answers with only two or three upvotes (this is a personal opinion). This new user can feel that these answers are not good. If, in addition, he or she sees a lot of downvotes on other answers, the conclusion can be that the site is not useful.

To summarize, I think that is natural that a site with few upvotes has also few downvotes, but I would like to see more voters on this site.

Yeah, I think that the main problem is that people seem to just not upvote on this site. I might ask a meta question specifically about this when I have some free time.

@DenisNardin: I think that the problem is that, lately, we are having very few voters on this site. From the site analytics one can see that we had 123 posts from the beginning of the year until now, but if you visit the "voters tab" you will see that only 6 users have voted more than 10 times this year (that includes up and down votes).

@Charo That looks like a very serious problem. Still, there are plenty of answered questions where the answerer did not upvote the question (usually there's only one upvote on the question, and it's mine). This seems to me a very bizarre behaviour: if the question is good enough to spend time to answer, it's certainly good enough to upvote!

I would like to add that, according to my own experience, downvotes to answers without any explanation often gives rise to perplexity of the OP and other users who use the site to learn Italian, which remain wondering about what is wrong in the answer.

Notice that some years ago I wrote "when an answer is of very evident low quality [...] there is no need to leave a comment to explain the reason of a downvote".
