L'andazzo recente con la votazione
Mi sono deciso nonostante tutti i trascorsi a scrivere questo post. Da un canto ci si lamenta del fatto della scarsa utenza, dall'altro riscontro una serie di downvotes riguardo a domande plausibli (quella di @charo oggi su "rimpolpare") e a risposte altrettanto plausibili come quelle di @reinstate sul futuro di "andare a". Trovo questo modo di fare vigliacco oltre che controproducente. Un downvote per una domanda non è giustificabile a meno che questa non sia al di là del bene e del male. Idem per le risposte. Possiamo trovare certi utenti più o meno simpatici, ma dovremmo essere in grado di separare l'aspetto personale da quello fattuale.

Non ho capito qual è la tua domanda qui (e il downvote a questa tua domanda su meta è mio). Comunque, non sono d'accordo che "un downvote per una domanda non è giustificabile a meno che questa non sia al di là del bene e del male".

Ti consiglio poi di partire da questa domanda https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/should-downvoters-leave-a-comment-to-explain-the-reason-of-their-downvote . Su questo sito, effettivamente, sembra che ogni tanto arrivino "drive-by downvotes" non spiegati o giustificati, a volte a raffica a molte domande recenti, e questo è spiacevole. Io sono un utente che tende a votare negativamente appena qualcosa non mi va, ma di solito non lo faccio indiscriminatamente e quando si chiede spiego il perché. (Non ho downvotato su "rimpolpare" né sui cuochi, a scanso di equivoci.)

@FedericoPoloni "Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works". Mi sembra abbastanza chiaro e a trarre un paio di inferenze non ci vuole molto. Personalmente trovo che un po' di trasparenza e meno infierimento non nuocerebbero. Questo era il messaggio (logicamente basato solo sulle mie esperienze).

A me invece continua a non essere chiaro quello che intendi anche con questo commento. Si vede che le inferenze non sono il mio forte. :)

Non ho capito il fatto del bene e del male, né che cosa c'entri Nietzsche. Se io passo il cursore sulle freccette per votare le risposte, mi dice “This answer is not useful” e “This answer is not useful”, ed è su questo che mi baso per i voti positivi e negativi.

@DaG Parlavo di "domande" e non di "risposte", se hai letto bene il mio post. Se una domanda ha un senso pertinente al sito non vedo perché dovrei votare negativamente. Tutt'al più non mi interessa, ma allora passo oltre. Voto negativamente una domanda solo nel caso in cui non sia formulata chiaramente e l'utente si rifiuti di fornire spiegazioni per motivi che non vuole addurre, cosa accaduta molto recentemente.

@DaG Non è mai troppo tardi volendo. https://www.ilgiornale.it/news/interni/pd-genera-mostri-906692.html  https://books.google.de/books?id=85AgBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT41&lpg=PT41&dq=%22%C3%A8+davvero+al+di+l%C3%A0+del+bene+e+del+male%22&source=bl&ots=6Wjw79Rfb5&sig=ACfU3U1BFHJoZCn7HdmzCZgtwqbe9_cSMg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBkKD-04PoAhWKsKQKHUIADosQ6AEwBHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A8%20davvero%20al%20di%20l%C3%A0%20del%20bene%20e%20del%20male%22&f=false

@Nico: Il criterio del “not useful” vale anche per le domande, e altri in più. Quindi, per semplici motivi logici, che una domanda rientri nei criteri per ammettere un voto negativo è ancora più probabile di quanto lo sia una risposta.

@Nico: “Non è mai troppo tardi volendo”: non so di che parli e non ho tempo per seguire i link, ma apprezzo molto il fatto che ti prendi a cuore la mia lacunosa cultura.

@DaG Allora perché chiedi cosa c'entra Nietzsche? Non ho fatto altro che risponderti.

@Nico: Grazie, ma non ho chiesto niente: ho scritto solo “Non ho capito il fatto del bene e del male, né che cosa c'entri Nietzsche”.

@DaG E come si giudicherebbe la pertinenza di una domanda?

@DaG "Non ho tempo per seguire i link". I see... Molto andreottiano! PS. I "link" non si seguono.

@DaG "Il criterio del “not useful” vale anche per le domande, e altri in più"  1) "E" come congiunzione vieta la virgola. 2) "Altri in più" non è italiano corrente. Cosa intendi?

Aggiungerei, riguardo al post dei cuochi su "andare a + infinito", un pensiero sulla domanda stessa (Perché i cuochi abusano nell'uso di "vado", "andiamo", "andrò" e simili?).
Immaginiamo che un utente straniero interessato all'italiano voglia ascoltare una di quelle trasmissioni di cucina, pensando: "è una trasmissione in un contesto tranquillo, dove una persona parla e spiega mentre tocca oggetti che conosco, e magari usa anche termini regionali, e infine parla di cucina che è una parte importante della cultura italiana. Posso imparare diverse cose, sentendole in un contesto reale, colloquiale, diretto, a differenza dell'italiano attento e colto che trovo sui libri."
Così l'utente si mette all'ascolto, compiaciuto della sua idea, e dopo dieci minuti nota che il verbo andare è usatissimo. Con impulso charesco domandarebbe su questo sito: "Cosa significa andare in questo contesto?". Ma potrebbe anche domandare, come ho fatto io, "Perchè i cuochi parlano così? Lo fanno tutti? Non è fastidioso e inutile quell'intercalare ossessivo di andare?".
Bene, tra risposte e commenti, questo è ciò che ho ricevuto:

la domanda è insensata
è una domanda sbagliata, qui non si parla di estetica
non è fastidioso
se lo trovi fastidioso, cambia canale
indignarsi per quel linguaggio strano è come indignarsi sul perchè le zebre hanno le strisce
quell'andare + infinito è la famosa costruzione di futuro imminente. Non può essere altro, dato che nei dizionari si trova solo quella.

Naturalmente io non sono quell'utente straniero (beh, più o meno, lasciamo stare), e per questo mi sono sentito discriminato.

Pienamente d'accordo!

Ti consiglierei di aggiungere un link alla domanda in questione, per comodità di chi legge.

Non ho capito quale sia il tuo punto qua (ma del resto non ho capito neppure la domanda). Perché quei commenti ti fanno sentire discriminato? Cosa c'è che non va in essi?

Inoltre, dal mio punto di vista, il nostro fantomatico utente straniero ha tutto il diritto di chiedere "Perchè i cuochi parlano così? Lo fanno tutti?", ma non "Non è fastidioso e inutile quell'intercalare ossessivo di andare?", perché questa è una domanda soggettiva e che in un sito come questo è considerata off-topic

@FedericoPoloni la domanda titola "perché i cuochi abusano...?", e dopo l'introduzione, anche opinabile, pone la domanda: "Ora chiedo: qualcuno ne sa qualche cosa di più?", assimilabile a "perché si usa xx per dire yy?". Per la discriminazione dico:  se due utenti che fanno la stessa cosa ma vengono trattati in modo diverso, allora uno dei due è discriminato.

Non ho capito quello che intendi dire. Chi sarebbe discriminato qua? Chi sono i "due utenti" del tuo esempio? Hai fatto una domanda in fondo legittima ma infarcita di opinioni personali off-topic per questo sito, e i downvotes mi sembrano ragionevoli. A te come a chiunque altro --- non vedo discriminazione qui; non fare l'errore comune di considerare i downvote come un'offesa personale.

...tra i commenti c'era un solo concetto che rispondeva alla domanda, che secondo me era sbagliato (nessuno lo ha ripreso come risposta). Segnalo che una domanda simile è stata posta alla Crusca, e la Crusca non ha certo risposto in modo sgarbato.

@FedericoPoloni i due utenti sono me stesso e un altro, immaginario, che non avrebbe ricevuto una simile sequela di critiche. Comunque non ho mai parlato di downvote, il discorso è diverso e riguarda l'atteggiamento. Per me il caso è chiuso.

Secondo me la stai prendendo troppo sul personale. Commenti come "se lo trovi fastidioso, cambia canale" o "la domanda è poco sensata" non sono un'offesa rivolta a te, ma indicano solo un certo modo 'descrittivo' di vedere la lingua italiana: non c'è "giusto" o "sbagliato", ma si può solo descrivere gli usi che si sono evoluti nel tempo. Per quanto riguarda commenti come "non è fastidioso", beh, a domanda soggettiva, risposta soggettiva. :)

@FedericoPoloni ti ringrazio per le considerazioni pacate, ma ripeto: il discorso è diverso. nico ha postato una risposta legittima a quella domanda; e pure la risposta è stata maltrattata. Come dire: "noi abbiamo deciso che la domanda è brutta, va criticata e non deve ricevere risposte; chi non si adegua se ne deve pentire". Se poi si scende nel merito, asserire che "siamo andati a dare ..." è un futuro imminente importato dal francese, è l'apoteosi. Dimostra chiusura mentale volontaria.

Mi sembra che quei downvote siano di merito, non "politici": sono accompagnati da commenti che spiegano dettagliatamente cosa non va, e le osservazioni fatte nei commenti mi sembrano perlomeno plausibili. Cosa ti spinge a pensare che invece abbiano motivazioni diverse? La maggior parte delle tue altre risposte sono in positivo, mi sembra (non hanno molti voti, è vero, ma questo è un problema globale del sito). Quindi non credo a una teoria che dice che la gente ce l'ha con te per qualche motivo.

Scusa @FedericoPoloni, vorrei veramente smettere di parlarne. Non ho scritto assolutamente niente sui downvote, neanche una parola. E' il tono dei commenti, l'atteggiamento verso di me e verso Nico, e l'insistenza nel voler sostenere una cosa senza approfondirla, per poi lamentarsi che il sito non va bene.

@linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Temo che qui lo spirito di combriccola latineggiante con tutte le sue implicazioni regni alla stragrande. Non esiste interesse vero, ma solo "se tu dai una cosa a me, io poi do una cosa a te". O forse meglio a mo' di Queen Latifah "When you are good to Mama, Mama is good to you".

Questa non è stata la prima domanda di Italian.SE che è rimasta con un bilancio di voti negativi, anzi, ce ne sono state parecchie, anche qualche mia domanda. Succede che queste domande frequentemente non ricevono nessuna risposta e allora sono automaticamente cancellate dal sistema passato un certo tempo (se gli OP non decidono di cancellarle prima). Sono le regole del gioco.
